# Is Ontario Parks waiving admission fees for a day in 2019?

Tags: fees-and-charges, national-parks, ontario

[This website](https://www.todocanada.ca/city/toronto/event/ontario-parks-free-use-day/) asseverates that July 19 2019 is "Ontario Parks Free Use Day", but has Ontario Parks officially blazoned this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a specific dated event that has already passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is of any value, the answer is yes.

http://www.ontarioparks.com/hphp/freedayuse

Comment: Boy am I unskilled at Googling. Thanks!