# Is Parks Canada waiving admission fees for a day in 2019 for 18+ Canadian citizens?

Tags: canada, canadian-citizens, national-parks

I know that [ON Parks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/139023/95173) is provincial and Parks Canada federal. I'm just ruminating if Parks Canada has a free use day too for all Canadians? Parks Canada blazons that

> As of January 1, 2018, admission to Parks Canada places for youth 17 and under has been free!
>
> Using the [Institute for Canadian Citizenship](http://www.icc-icc.ca/en/)'s Canoo mobile app, enjoy free admission to Parks Canada locations across the country for one full year after your Citizenship ceremony.

But what if you're 18+ and you've been a citizen for more than one year?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be a historical question and has no future value.

Comment: @GregHewgill What does TSE gain by getting rid of this question? The question is on topic and already answered, so why not just leave it here in case someone searches for exactly this bit of information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [website of Park Canada](https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/voyage-travel/admission) the two categories you mentioned get free access:

- Youth below 18
- New citizens in their first year

There is no mention of any other category that I can find anywhere. However, last year (2018) there were occasions where access was free for anyone:

- [Each park had its own free day](https://www.mtlblog.com/news/all-national-parks-in-canada-will-be-free-in-2018)
- [Access to all parks was free for Canada day](https://www.canada.ca/en/parks-canada/news/2018/06/join-us-to-celebrate-canada-day-at-banff-yoho-and-kootenay-national-parks.html)

The free day for each park seems not to happen this year (2019) and I couldn't find any information for Canada Day either, but looking at the link from last year, the press release was from 27 June with Canada Day being on 1 July, so it might still happen.